# How to find whitespace and store into variable?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

In this program, I am trying to find the white space of my array, and store that value into a variable then print out that variable. The only function I know to use is the isspace one, and when I used it the error I recieve is: 'isspace' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [80]' to 'int'

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
// Zachary Law Strings.cpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>


int main()
{   int x, i,y;
char name[] = "Please enter your name: ";
char answer1 [80];
i=0;
y=0;

cout << name;
cin.getline(answer1, 79);
cout << endl;

x=strlen(answer1);

 for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    cout << answer1[i] << endl;
    if (isspace(answer1)) 
    {y=y+1;}}

 cout << endl << endl;
 cout << setw(80) << answer1;

 cout <<y;




return 0;}
```

Comment: I think you are sending a array instead of a char to your isspace function that's what I understand from your error, instead of answer1 try answer1[i]...

Answer (score 2):

Each narrow character classification function takes an `int` argument that is either non-negative or the special value `EOF`. Otherwise the behavior is undefined. And with most C++ implementations `char` is a signed type, so that sufficiently high values (in effect, all characters outside ASCII) become negative.

So cast the argument to `unsigned char`, after adding the relevant indexing,

```
if( isspace( (unsigned char) answer1[i] ) )
```

Then the resulting non-negative value will be implicitly converted to `int`.

---

Instead of placing a cast in every invocation of a classification function, consider wrapping them in more C++-friendly fashion, e.g.

```
auto is_space( char const c )
    -> bool
{ return ::isspace( (unsigned char) c ); }
```

Answer (score 1):

try the below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    cout << answer1[i] << endl;
    if (isspace(answer1[i])) 
    {y=y+1;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said earlier, you pass a array instead of a char to isspace function.

isspace function accept:
int isspace ( int c );

```
/* isspace example */
#include <stdio.h>


#include <ctype.h>
int main ()
{
  char c;
  int i=0;
  char str[]="Example sentence to test isspace\n";
  while (str[i])
  {
    c=str[i];
    if (isspace(c)) c='\n';
    putchar (c);
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```